# Settings.Designer.cs vs Web.config

Tags: web-config, appsettings

I have just joined a project that has a connection string which is defined in the Settings.Designer.cs file and also defined in the web.config file.  When I need to look at a different instance of my DB I have to modify both values.  I am unfamilier with why the Settings.Designer.cs file is being used.  What is the value of using Settings.Designer.cs vs web.config?  Assuming I can remove one of the connection string entries...should it be removed from Settings.Designer.cs or from web.config?

Comment: i read here that.   web.config is created by settings.designer.cs.
according to this . if i edit connectionStrings in Settingsdesigner.cs  . than it will reconfigure/overwrite the app/web.config file. (also ihave been struggling with old ConStrings when compiling ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768277/force-regeneration-of-settings-settings-file-after-change-in-app-config/3769365#3769365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Winforms guy myself, and now working on a web project, my guess is that the Settings.Designer.cs was being used by a winforms guy working on a website :)

I would probably blow away the connection string in Settings.Designer.cs

Comment: @Taylor...thanks.  That does sound plausible.  I was wondering if there was a hidden reason for it.  :) Let's see how other folks chime in.