# can't connect to sql 2012 in asp.net , c# due to app.config , settings.designer.cs not regenerating

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i cant connect to sql 2012 in  asp.net , c#

file: defalut.aspx  -> page_Load

```
List<ozhatdata.tbl_diller> diller_result;
using (var ctx = new ozhatdata.bagDataContext())
{
   diller_result = ozhatdata.DilIslemleri.GetAllLanguages(ctx);
}
int cnt = diller_result.Count  ;  // diller_result is null error
```

when i go to definition (F12) of the bagDataContext()
file: bag.designer.cs

```
public bagDataContext() : 
base(global::ozhatdata.Properties.Settings.Default.ozhatprojeConnectionString15, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

when i go to definition (F12) of ozhatprojeConnectionString15
file: settings.designer.cs

```
  [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
  [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
  [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
  [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute( "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ozhatproje;Persist Security Info=True;"+
        "User ID=sa;Password=123; ")]
  public string ozhatprojeConnectionString15 {
      get {
          return ((string)(this["ozhatprojeConnectionString15"]));
      }
  }
```

*later i learned there is app.config file* this line was present in app.config

```
<add name="Settings.ozhatprojeConnectionString15" 
connectionString="Data Source=LIVE2RISE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ozhatproje;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

i can connect to "user:sa pass:123" on "ms sql management studio"

!!!!error!!!!!!

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    diller_result.count  // this  diller_result is null in debugger

```
line 36:   for (int i = 0; i < diller_result.Count; i++)

Kaynak Dosya: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\Default.aspx.cs    line : 36
```

im trying to figure out since yesterday.
please help me, thnks.

**edit:**  after  responce i tracked adn put a breakpoint

```
 public static List<tbl_diller> GetAllLanguages(bagDataContext ctx = null)
 {
     try
     {
         //some stuf was here i deleted
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        string ms = ex.Message;   // !!breakpoint 
        // the exception= coundt find stored procedure "dbo.getalllangs"
         return null;
     }
    }
```

thank you. the problem is solved.  it was caused by an evil try-cath duo.
i'll be more cautious with these "try catchs" from now on.

**2nd time and Solution**: this time  eventhough i edit app.config, program uses old ConString from settings.designer.cs(i tracked it while debugging).

**the program uses connString from  setting.designer.cs too. app.config is not used/looked up/referred when Debugging**

so we have to navigate in the solution>properties>settings.designer.cs  edit connectionStrings  there too.

i hope this helps anyone in future.
you can read this too: 
[Force regeneration of Settings.settings file after change in app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768277/force-regeneration-of-settings-settings-file-after-change-in-app-config)

Comment: What is your error message? -- And since your update, your connection strings are different in `settings.designer.cs` (referencing the local machine) compared to `app.config` (referencing specific server name)

Comment: null refence exception

Comment: shouldt designer.cs  fix itself  if i change anytihng in app.config ?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Your settings file defines the default value.  Once compiled, it can be changed by your config file.

Comment: both of that server are on my local pc  .

Comment: If `diller_result` is null, that doesn't have to mean that you can't connect to the database.  When you debug, check to see that `ozhatdata` , `ozhatdata.DilIslemleri` and `ctx` all have values and are not null as well.

Comment: yes checked  it . and found try catch was eating the error it was a missing stored procedure in database which i previosly only copied the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is the call to `ozhatdata.DilIslemleri.GetAllLanguages`that did return a `null` value for `diller_result`.

You might want to check in that method what is causing it to return `null`.

Comment: i love you so much .  there was a try catch  where you said.   i read the exception message it was "store procedure was missing". actually i only imported the tables anytings else was not  in my copy_of_db.